# What is an ROC curve?

Tags: computer-vision, tracking, roc

Can someone be kind enough to explain what an ROC curve actually represents with respect to tracking in a test sequence please? An example of an ROC curve is shown in the figure below.

[image]

Comment: *A ROC curve is a graphical plot comparing the true positive and false positive rates of a classifier as its discrimination threshold is varied.* ~[Stack Overflow's wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/roc/info)

Comment: Ok . So the screenshot I have put is from "Detecting Pedestrians Using Patterns of Motion and Appearance" of Paul Viola and M.Jones. So in their perspective what is the discrimination threshold you are referring to please?

Comment: have a look [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ba-predictive-analytics3/)

Comment: If you want a dynamic illustration look at this: http://www.navan.name/roc/

Answer (score 2):

The comments to the original question contain some very useful links to understand ROC curves in general and the discrimination threshold in question. Here is an attempt to understand the reference (Ref. 1) used by the OP and further information specific to the problem of Detecting Pedestrians.

How the ROC Curves are obtained in (Ref. 1) and what is the discrimination threshold in this case:

1. Motion filters and appearance filters, ("f_i" in eq. (2) p. 156) are evaluated using "integral image" of various time/spatial difference images from video sequences.
2. Using all these filters the learning algorithm builds the best classifier, (C in eq. (1) p. 156), separating positive examples ( e.g: pedestrians ) from negative examples (e.g: selection of non-pedestrian examples ). The classifier, C, is a thresholded sum of features, F, as given in eq. (1). A feature, F, is a filter, "f_i" thresholded by a feature threshold "t_i".
3. The thresholds involved (i.e., filter thresholds, "t_i" and classifier threshold "Theta") are computed during AdaBoost training that chooses the features with the lowest weighted error on the training examples.
4. As in (Ref. 2), a cascade of such classifiers is used to make the detector extremely efficient. During training each stage of the cascade - boosted classifier - is trained using 2250 positive examples (example in Fig. 5 p. 158) and 2250 negative examples.
5. The final cascade detector is run over a validation sequences to obtain the true positive rate and the false positive rate. This is based on comparing the output of the cascade detector (e.g., presence or absence of a pedestrian) to the ground truth (presence or absence of a pedestrian at the same region based on ground truth or manual review of the video sequence). For a set of threshold values for the entire cascade ("t_i" and "Theta" over all classifier in the cascade) a certain true positive rate and false positive rate is obtained. This will make one point on the ROC curve.
6. A simple MATLAB example for measuring True Positive Rate and False Positive Rate from a given set of classifier outputs and ground truth can be found here: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21212-confusion-matrix---matching-matrix-along-with-precision--sensitivity--specificity-and-model-accuracy
7. So in this case, each point on the ROC curve will depend on the thresholds chosen for all the cascade layers (hence the discriminative threshold is not a single number in this case). By adjusting  these thresholds, one at a time, the output values of true positive rate and false positive rate change (when step 5 is repeated) giving other points on the ROC curve.
8. This process is repeated for both cases of dynamic and static detectors to obtain the two ROC curves on the figure.

Please go through some more good description and examples through this link on [ROC](http://ebp.uga.edu/courses/Chapter%204%20-%20Diagnosis%20I/8%20-%20ROC%20curves.html):

ROC curves can be used to compare the performance of classifiers in distinguishing between classes, as example, pedestrian versus non-pedestrian input samples. The area under the ROC curve is used as a measure of the classifier's ability to distinguish between the classes.

Quotes are from:

(Ref. 1) P. Viola, M. J. Jones, and D. Snow, "Detecting Pedestrians Using Patterns of Motion and Appearance", International Journal of Computer Vision 63(2), 153-161, 2005. [online: as of April 2015] http://lear.inrialpes.fr/people/triggs/student/vj/viola-ijcv05.pdf

(Ref. 2) P. Viola and M. J. Jones, "Rapid object detection using a boosted cascade of simple features. In IEEE Conference on Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition. More information at [Viola-Jones Algorithm - "Sum of Pixels"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23171232/viola-jones-algorithm-sum-of-pixels)